# How to get "owner instance" of the class instance in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have two classes, I'd like to get the attribute of the "owner" class from instance created, see the code bellow...

```
class A{      
  String test
  A(){
   //How to get the value of "test" property of the class B from here?
   //
 }
}



class B{

String test

  def doSomething(){
      //I'd like that instance of A get the value of "test" attribute without pass it by param   
      A a = new A() //like this

      A a = new A(test:test) //I don't want to do this


  }

}
```

Comment: I don't get it. How do you expect A to know about B?

Comment: I want that the instance created(Class A) get the "owner", so, the instance of class B, but the instance of class A shouldn't know about class B. hahaha it's not so easy, I know, but I think is not possible, before I find one solution I'll use like this   `A a = new A(test:test)`, thank you for comment

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def doSomething(){
  A a = new A() 
  a.test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it without an instance. 
Class A doesn't know about class B.
You can create a constructor with B as parameter.

```
class A{
    A(B b){
     println b.test
    }
}
```

and then you can use it in B like this:

```
doSomething(){
  new A(this)
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to pass the param by constructor, so, like I want is not possible right?

Comment: It's not posible. Maybe with Java Reflections but it's crazy

Comment: You can do something like that:
class B {static Map<A,B> instances = new HashMap();
B(){
instances.put(new A(),this)
}
}
than you can use it in A like:

B.instances.get(this) // this = instance of A

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern
But you should understand what are you doing, if you use this.

Comment: OK guys, I think is not possible, until I find one solution I'll use like this `A a = new A(test:test)` Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but you can have a kind of ownership relationship using a non-static inner class A. Works in Groovy the same as in Java.

```
class B {
  class A {
    def knowYourOwner() {
      // access the outer class' property directly via test
      println "My owner says: '$test'"
      // or explicitly via B.this.test (to avoid conflicts with local variables 'test')
      def test = 'another string'
      println "My owner says: '${B.this.test}'"
    }
  }

  String test
  def doSomething() {
    A a = new A()
    a.knowYourOwner()
  }
}

def b = new B(test: 'I am B')
b.doSomething()
```

Comment: Almost! The both classes can't have any relationship, the classes are independent, I just want to "get the owner" of the class that was created, if it's possible I'm sure it need to be a language feature, I think is not possible to do that with workaround! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the test property of class B a static member variable

```
class A { 
  String test

  A() {
    this.test = B.test
  }
}

class B {
  static String test
}

def b = new B(test: "someString")
def a = new A()

println a.test  // outputs : "someString"
```